# How to push arrays into a methods with C

Tags: c, arrays

Trying to write a program that generates a list of 1000 random integers b/w 0 & 1000, then find the first instance that a certain number of my choice (denoted as "iNum" and equal to 27 in this case), and then find the total number of times that said number (iNum) appears within this array.

The First() method is to find the first time that iNum appears in the array, and the Total() method is to find the total number of times iNum appears in the array.

Although the random number generator is working just fine, I can't seem to find a way to "push" the random array (denoted as "aRanArray") as well as iNum into the method to perform the operations.

Here is my Main.c program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "RanNum.h"

int main()
{
  //The arbitrary number to be looked for
  int iNum = 27;
  int iFirst = 0;
  int iTotal = 0;
  int aRanArray[1000];

  //Generating the random aRanArray
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
  {
    //Fills array
    aRanArray[i] = rand() % 1000;

    //Prints out numbers within array
    printf("%d ", aRanArray[i]);
  }
  //Finding the first time iNum appears in aRanArray
  iFirst = First(aRanArray, iNum);

  //Finding the number of times iNum appears in aRanArray
  iTotal = Total(aRanArray, iNum);

  //Printing out the values
  printf ("%d", iFirst);
  printf ("%d", iTotal);
}
```

My method to find the first instance of iNum within this random array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "RanNum.h"

//Finding the first time iNum Appears in the array
int First(aRanArray*, iNum)
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
  {
    if(*aRanArray[i] == iNum)
    {
      return *aRanArray[i];
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

My method to find the total number of times iNum shows up in my array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "RanNum.h"

//Finding the total number of times iNum
//appears in aRanArray
int Total(aRanArray*, iNum)
{
  int iTotal = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
  {
    if(*aRanArray[i] == iNum)
    {
      iTotal++;
    }
  }
  return iTotal;
}
```

And my RanNum.h file for my methods:

```
#ifndef RANCOUNT
#define RANCOUNT
int First(int*, int);
int Total(int*, int);
#endif
```

The error message I keep getting is"unkonw type name for both aRanArray and iNum in both First() and Total().

Comment: because those aren't the names of types - they are the names of your variables

Comment: try `< 1000` not `<=` (for starters!)

Answer (score 0):

```
int First(aRanArray*, iNum)
```

needs to be

```
int First( int *aRanArray, int iNum )
```

to match the prototype in `RanNum.h`:

```
int First(int*, int);
```

Same deal with the `Total` function.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks for taking the time.